# ArcGIS Pro Spatial Join does not join all features

Tags: arcgis-pro, spatial-join

I'm trying to do a spatial join of a point layer and a polygon layer in ArcGIS Pro 3.0.3 - the information of the polygons (names of protected areas) should be added to the points within the polygons. Each time I try to perfom the spatial join, only 130 points are joined. Obviously, a lot of the other points (1600 in total) are not counted, the information is not added. I tried the match options intersect and whithin. The same happens when I try to add a relate.
The screenshot shows the selection of the points on which the spatial join worked.
Does anyone have an idea on whats wrong here? Its the first time ever I have such a problem with spatial join...

[image: spatial join not working properly]

Comment: Are your target features the points or the polygons?  I suspect they are your polygons and you're instructing the tool to just get one point for each polygon instead of one polygon for each point.

Comment: Also, are the two feature classes in the same coordinate system?

Comment: Also confirm your input data is not multi-part?

Comment: The target features are the points and both layers have the same coordinate system. I already performed a transformation on the polygon layer because I expected that to be a problem..

Comment: Actually, the polygon layer was multipart!! I did not realize (open dataset). Thank you so much, I transformed it to a singlepart layer and now the spatial join worked correctly.

Comment: Could you maybe explain why this caused the problem? I think spatial joins with multi-part polygons already worked before.